# How can you view the IP addresses of active MongoDB Atlas connections?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

[Some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971216/how-can-i-check-for-mongodbs-active-connections-status-using-java-driver) show you can use db.currentOp(true) to show active connections, but when I do that I get this error

`{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Using $all for currentOp is disallowed in this atlas tier",
        "code" : 8000,
        "codeName" : "AtlasError"
}`

Is there another way to view active connections to a MongoDB Atlas Cluster? What tier allows you to use this command?

Comment: What tier are you using?

Comment: Free Tier, we're moving to M10 during deployment though

Comment: @A_toaster, What IP address, you want to view? I mean to say that Public IP or Private IP.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Public IP. there are some remote devices connecting to the db and I'd like to see where they are coming from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is about how to view ip addresses that got connected to your mongoDB Atlas cluster, I would say you can see number of connections established to a cluster by just logging into your Atlas mongoDB cloud dashboard ([Atlas login](https://cloud.mongodb.com/user#/atlas/login)). But if you want details on connections established, then you can download logs for that particular cluster as a file, You can navigate to it as given below, but you might only see this option for paid versions, Technically `db.currentOp(true)` should work, but for some reason it didn't, not sure why, maybe unsupported !! ([mongoDB-unsupported-commands](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/unsupported-commands/)) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB Atlas Free tier, In the **Cluster Overview** page you should be able to the see the number active connections to the cluster as shown below.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Since Atlas Free Tier doesn't allow to run `db.currentOp()`, The one other way is to check the MongoDB log files for active connection IP Address. In the log file look for the latest entry like below

```
2019-03-28T09:42:49.795-0700 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 192.168.1.1:62408 #1 (1 connection now open)
```

This will give you the number of active connections and from which are IP address the connection is made. Also, to check the connections is closed or not

```
2019-03-28T09:51:48.797-0700 I NETWORK  [conn7] end connection 192.168.1.1:62408 (0 connections now open)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can you view the IP addresses of active MongoDB Atlas connections?

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/atlas-free-tier-setup/) the IP address has been added in Atlas cluster will appears under the Check the **`IP Whitelist`** section under the **`Security`** tab.

For example in screenshot It has been chosen as `IP Whitelist` as Any to Any ( i.e IP address is 0.0.0.0/0). If you shall chose your current IP address in `IP Whitelist` then it will show your current Public IP address.

[image]

After Edit

Suppose that during the **Security IP Whitelist**  configuration time,I have been added my IP Address through the **ADD IP Address** button as it's appear on the right top corner of the Cluster window screen such as

[image]

After adding my Public IP (37.186.35.171/32)is appears like that

[image]

And the status of the connection is shows as **ACTIVE** status. Even I have logged two times from the Atlas cluster and again login to the cluster as it's always IP Address is appearing as 37.186.35.171/32. Which I have been red highlighted through arrow in the screenshot.

Comment: The `IP Whitelist` page show from which are all IP Address or IP address rage this cluster will accept the connections. For example, if I add `0.0.0.0` to the IP Whitelist it will accept connection from all IP address range but it won't show you specifically from which IP Address I am connected from.

Comment: @Mani, The IP address 0.0.0.0/0 I have been taken because it's allow ANY to ANY connections. Even i have written on the same line if you shall configure your **current IP Address** then it will auto take your current Public IP Address.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. What I am trying to say here is, the IP white list page will not help you to identify the active connection's IP Adress values. Consider I have added an IP address added to the IP Whitelist group but I haven't connected to the cluster from the IP address, still, the IP Adress will be displayed in the IP Whitelist page.

Comment: @Mani,Consider I have added an IP address added to the IP Whitelist group but I haven't connected to the cluster from the IP address, still, the IP Adress will be displayed in the IP Whitelist page. **YES** Because Public IP and their subnet mask will be always remain intact there in **IP Whitelist**.

Comment: The question here is `How can you view the IP addresses of active MongoDB Atlas connections?` and I am trying to say IP Whitelist page may not help to answer the question.

Comment: @Mani, One thing I will remind to you,  As MongoDB Cluster IP Whitelist address always take the Public IP address in the cluster.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Consider based on my IP whitelist entries you should be able to connect from 10 different public IP addresses to the mongodb instance. but at that moment only 5 public IP addresses are connected to the instance. how will I identify what are all the 5 IP address connected to the cluster out of 10 IPs?

Comment: @Mani,One thing is there if you configure through your IP Address, then only that IP Address you shall able to access your cluster data set. If you shall configure 0.0.0.0/0 then you shall be able to access from **ANYWHERE**.

Comment: @Mani,Correct me if I am wrong. Consider based on my IP whitelist entries you should be able to connect from 10 different public IP addresses to the mongodb instance. but at that moment only 5 public IP addresses are connected to the instance. how will I identify what are all the 5 IP address connected to the cluster out of 10 IPs? kindly ask to another question? It will be future reference to the other MongoDB professionals.

Comment: if my understanding is correct the actual question is the same, but I explained with an example.